# Add page break to Reportlab Canvas object

Tags: python, reportlab

I need to generate a 2 pages pdf report. Pages are completely independent. tried using:

```
mycanvas.drawString(x, y, "Printing on Page 1")
mycanvas._pageNumer = 2
mycanvas.drawString(x, y, "Printing on Page 2")
```

and:

```
mycanvas.drawString(x, y, "Printing on Page 1")
P = PageBreak()
P.drawOn(mycanvas, 0, 1000)
mycanvas.drawString(x, y, "Printing on Page 2")
```

But everything is printed on the same page.

How should I add a page break to this Canvas instance ?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Just call `mycanvas.showPage()` once page 1 is done -- this way, the rest of the output goes to page 2.  See [the docs](https://www.reportlab.com/docs/reportlab-reference.pdf).

Comment: oops! shame on me! promise to read slower next time, thanks :)

Comment: Finding this answer on SO was faster than searching in the reportlab PDF doc, so thanks for having posted it @juanefren :)

Comment: running "showPage()" function did not my my subsequent elements on a new page though