# showPage interferes with laterPages template in reportlab

Tags: python, canvas, footer, reportlab

I am trying to generate a PDF with reportlab that has headers and footers starting on the second page.

I read the threads:
 [Add page break to Reportlab Canvas object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593193/add-page-break-to-reportlab-canvas-object) 
and [Non-numbered pages in ReportLab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4956283/non-numbered-pages-in-reportlab?rq=1)

Using functions from these threads I can sucessfully close the title page with 
    **canvas.showPage()**
and can sucessfully start headers/ footers using 
    **doc.build(Story, onFirstPage=myFirstPage, onLaterPages=myLaterPages)**.

However, when I close the **canvas.showPage()**, my headers and footers begin on page THREE, not page TWO.

CODE:

```
def firstPage(canvas,doc):
    canvas.setFont('Times-Bold',40)
    canvas.drawString(inch, pageHeight-(3*inch), 'docTitle1') #w,h,txt
    canvas.drawString(2*inch, pageHeight-(4*inch), 'docTitle2')
    canvas.showPage() #force pagebreak

def laterPages(canvas, doc):
    canvas.saveState()
    canvas.setFont('Times-Roman',9)
    canvas.setStrokeColorRGB(2,2,2) #169,169,169)

    canvas.drawString(0.5*inch, pageHeight-(0.75*inch), 'header1')
    canvas.drawString(pageWidth-inch, pageHeight-(0.75*inch), 'header2')
    canvas.drawCentredString(pageWidth/2, 0.65*inch, 'footer1')
    canvas.drawCentredString(pageWidth/2, 0.5*inch, 'footer2')
    canvas.drawString(pageWidth-inch, 0.6*inch, `doc.page`) #page number
    canvas.restoreState()

def build_pdf(elements, doc_name):
    doc = SimpleDocTemplate(doc_name)
    doc.build(elements, onFirstPage=firstPage, onLaterPages=laterPages)

elements = [title, table1, spacer]
doc_name = 'myPDF.pdf'

build_pdf(elements, doc_name)
```

How can i stop drawing on the first page and still have onLaterPages begin on page TWO?

Comment: I think onLaterPages is meant to be used with flowables that automagically flow to subsequent pages... If you are manually adding page breaks I think you are better off just making a AddHeader / addFooter method and calling it after showPage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
doc.append(PageBreak())
```

for closing a page and opening the next one.

Comment: ended up adding Title and PageBreak() to elements outside of the firstPage function. Working!! (btw for newbies, from reportlab.platypus.flowables import PageBreak). thx